# Visualize XGB using plot_tree on Macbook

Tags: python, graphviz, xgboost

I am trying to visualize the tree using xgb's built-in function "plot_tree" on a Macbook:

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBRegressor, plot_tree

X = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100).reshape(100, 1)
y = np.random.randint(0, 500, 100).reshape(100, 1)

model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators = 1)

model.fit(X, y)


plot_tree(model)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpng'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

I tried with: 
1. brew install graphviz
2. Set before at the beginning of the script

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/Users/alessandro/opt/anaconda3/bin/"
```

However, the do not seem to be working, reporting the same error.

How can I visualize the single tree I've trained using Graphviz or alternative solutions?

Comment: If you open Terminal and execute `type dot`, what do you get?

Comment: I get: "/usr/local/bin/dot" ; i tried to run the above script with os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/local/bin/dot" but it raises "NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'dot'" @SaaruLindestøkke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `dot` command is located in the folder `/usr/local/bin/`.

You can either add that folder to your PATH globally with the following terminal commands:

```sh
sudo nano /etc/paths
*type passsword*
```

Then add the line `/usr/local/bin` to the file, or if it's already there, move it to the top of the list.

To only add that folder to your PATH in this script I think you're command is very close, but needs slight adjustment:

```py
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/local/bin/"
```

Not the omission of `dot` as you're trying to add the folder, not the executable to the PATH.